# dynamic environment file extension

Tags: angular, environment-variables, http-headers

I am trying to handle a micro front-end with multiple different 'clients' using the same env file with different extensions for example:

```
 this.client = 'CLIENTONE';

    // this is the default body to send to httpHeaders
    const httpBody = {
      apibase: env.${this.client}.apibase,
    };
    // turn above body into a header to use in requests
    this.headerBody = { headers: httpBody };
    // END //
```

The above example does not work but shows the solution I tried.

Here is the env file example:

```
export const CLIENTONE= {
    production: false,
    apibase: 'https://apiBase/clientOne',
  };

export const CLIENTTWO= {
    production: false,
    apiBase: 'https://apiBase/clientTwo'
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach it like this - structure the environment file with a 'dictionary' of options in instead:

```
export const environment = {
  CLIENTONE: {
    production: false,
    apibase: 'https://apiBase/clientOne'
  },
  CLIENTTWO: {
    production: false,
    apiBase: 'https://apiBase/clientTwo'
  }
};
```

If you then defined your `client` variable with type `'CLIENTONE' | 'CLIENTTWO'`, for example like this:

```
client: 'CLIENTONE' | 'CLIENTTWO' = 'CLIENTONE';
```

You could then access this, building on your example, like:

```
this.client = 'CLIENTONE';

// this is the default body to send to httpHeaders
const httpBody = {
  apibase: environment[this.client].apiBase,
};
// turn above body into a header to use in requests
  this.headerBody = { headers: httpBody };
// END //
```

Comment: I am not to sure what you mean with this: client: 'CLIENTONE' | 'CLIENTTWO' = 'CLIENTONE';

The error I currently get with your solution: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type `

Comment: Mean to give your client property type `'CLIENTONE' | 'CLIENTTWO'`, in the same way you would say give type `string` or `number` ect.